# MiniDumpWriteDump another process

Tags: c, dump, minidumpwritedump

I'm trying to create a service with the goal of monitor the applications created by my company.

When the app gets the state of No responding, the service have to generate a a dump with `MiniDumpWriteDump`.

The problem is: when using `HANDLE` of another process, the `MiniDumpWriteDump` doesn't work. The .dmp file stays empty.

`GetLastError` returns 0xD0000008 (3489660936)

That function is to get `HANDLE` by pid:

```
void CDumpGenerator::FindAndSetHandle()
{
    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

    EnableDebugPriv();

    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);

        return;
    }

    do
    {
        hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);

        if (hProcess != NULL)
            CloseHandle(hProcess);

        if (pe32.th32ProcessID == this->pid)
        {
            this->processHandle = hProcess;

            break;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
}
```

EnableDebugPriv:

```
void EnableDebugPriv()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    LUID luid;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid);

    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &tkp, sizeof(tkp), NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(hToken);
}
```

And i'm calling `MiniDumpWriteDump` this way:

```
auto dumped = MiniDumpWriteDump(
    this->processHandle,
    this->pid,
    hFile,
    MINIDUMP_TYPE(MiniDumpNormal | MiniDumpWithThreadInfo |  MiniDumpWithProcessThreadData | MiniDumpWithFullMemoryInfo),
    nullptr,
    &userStream,
    nullptr);
```

When I change `this->processHandle` to `GetCurrentProcess()` works fine.

Handle being set:

[image]

Here is the `GetLastError()`

[image]

Comment: Improve the error reporting so we don't have to guess why "it didn't work".  Call GetLastError() when it returns FALSE.  Also run SysInternals' ProcDump utility to see if it has any better luck, that localizes the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant The `GetLastError` returns me 0xD0000008. I didn't knew about ProcDump. I will see.

Comment: That's obscure, but looks a lot like an "invalid handle" error.  It is notable that FindAndSetHandle() can't tell you that it failed to find the process, that's not good.  Could be the hFile as well.

Comment: @HansPassant I change to `GetCurrentProcess` works and all dump is wrote so I think it's not `CreateFileA`. When I was debugging line by line on `FindAndSetHandle` I see the processHandle being setted.

Comment: Another bug in FindAndSetHandle() is that it generates a bad handle value when OpenProcess() failed.  Do take care of the basics, cuts down on the guessing.

Comment: But when I know if OpenProcess fails if I don't get any throw or anything different. I have an unmanaged class in C# that does exactly what C ++ does but it works normally using OpenProcess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem removing this part

```
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);

// This close handle
if (hProcess != NULL)
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

It's a simple thing that went unseen. So we need close handle on other part of code like destructor or anything else.